# VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-multidex

I'm getting the following error.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

- VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
- install
- VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
- install
- VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
- Shutting down VM

here is my build.gradle,i have enables the multidex in the android part,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.newlogin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {

}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
//compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

and my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.newlogin" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have a class extending from Application?

Comment: I have class MainActivity that extends AppCompactActivity

Comment: From the docs: This library provides compatibility for platforms with API level 4 through 20. This library does nothing on newer versions of the platform which provide built-in support for secondary dex files. I checked their code on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.java)

Answer (score 4):

create a class lets name it `App` and extend from `MultiDexApplication` like this:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
    //you can leave this empty or override methods if you like so the thing is that you need to extend from MultiDexApplication
}
```

in your manifest add `App` as your application name just like this

```
<application
        android:name=".App" // <<< this is the important line!
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

After adding everything make a clean build and it should work now :).

Comment: I have uploaded my manifest file,please take a look and help me to where to add your <application/> in my manifest file

Comment: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` -> Replace this with your custom class.

Comment: Hi Baniares and Kientux thank you guys for the help.                                   iam getting some null point exception error but dont know why?So help me to resolver this.

Comment: dude, I think this is not an error , The vm has already have the support of multidex that is why they are disabling , try to check the log in below 5.0.  I guess the the ART vm have already have the multidex support

Answer (score 1):

Override attachBaseContext method in your application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: That assumes there is a class which extends **Application**