# Android app launch first time launch is taking more time even some time 30 sec and more

Tags: android, delay, android-multidex

Below is log when app is first time installing:

> 05-12 13:16:23.632 28250-28250/com.app.projectName W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.app.projectName-1/lib/arm
>   05-12 13:16:59.041 28250-28250/com.app.projectName W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.app.projectName-1/lib/arm
>   05-12 13:16:59.073 28250-28250/com.app.projectName I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
>   05-12 13:16:59.073 28250-28250/com.app.projectName I/MultiDex: install
>   05-12 13:16:59.073 28250-28250/com.app.projectName I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.

And I am using `MultiDex` library in my project it will work completely below pre lollipop devices.This delay varying in Lollipop devices between 30 sec to 90 sec first time app start up.

See it is not due to `MultiDex` right? because when time is 1.) initializing **05-12 13:16:23.632** and second log comes after 36 second which is **05-12 13:16:59.041**

That thing creates app delay `ClassLoader` referenced.... `MultiDex` is initializing fast. Below is the screen shot [image] It is taking 15 seconds to 30 seconds and sometime even more.

**My Gradle file is:**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.1.2'
compile 'co.lujun:androidtagview:1.0.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.0.0'
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.greysonparrelli.permiso:permiso:0.2.0'
compile 'com.github.lawloretienne:imagegallery:0.0.14'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
compile 'com.github.mahmed8003:DroidValidatorLight:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.1.+'
compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

Any help appreciate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326575/vm-has-multidex-support-multidex-support-library-is-disabled/33327028

Comment: already saw this link and there is no delay for multidex due to some other some ClassLoader creates delay see log inside timings. 05-12 13:16:23.632 second line is 05-12 13:16:59.041 and in lollipop devices multidex will not work [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459692/application-or-activity-takes-time-to-load-some-times/37460527#37460527

Comment: disable instant run and this issue will be fixed. Also seeing this thread may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Comment: ok thank you for prompt reply @Amir

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally found answer after more then 16 days all thanks to you @Amir. Correct answer is to disabling instant run then run. There is a strange issue with newly released Android Studio 2.0 &  2.1. first time of launching application take longer than usual this issue happens only in debug mode and not effect your released APK.

```
Settings/Preferences(Mac) → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Instant Run
```

Comment: WOW after doing this. App started like a rocket launcher

Comment: It does not load fast during the first load, on subsequent loads it does. Superb @Amir

Comment: It has improved a lot. But my app still shows a white screen for a sec. Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: @Zartha i am facing that issue also once i get that solution i come back here and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

**Settings/Preferences(Mac) → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Instant Run**

[image]

I was also facing the same problem and finally i fixed this. 
**note:** 
1) before generating an apk file unchecked all these option to resolve delay issue from your production build. 

2) while you are developing or adding new features then keep it as default setting(instant run) to make development faster.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I already Solved issue please refer marked answer!!! and you share same solution as i did earlier. No need to repeat answers round and round.

Comment: look flow would be same, but what we mentioned it's different. just have a look.