# Application or activity takes time to load some times

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity

I have created a startup activity from where I am calling another activity which has a view pager and shows some introductory pages.

This app was taking time to load so I thought to display a progress dialog till the activity loads, but that progress dialog also appears few seconds later.

startup activity:

```
public class StartUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean isUserFirstTime, login;
    public static String PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isUserFirstTime = Boolean.valueOf(Utils.readSharedSetting(StartUpActivity.this, PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, "true"));
        Intent introIntent = new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, SlidingActivity.class);
        introIntent.putExtra(PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, isUserFirstTime);

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(StartUpActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Welcome to Mea Vita, please wait till the app loads.");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        dialog.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Here you can send the extras.

                startActivity(new Intent(StartUpActivity.this,SlidingActivity.class));

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

This doesn't happen every time,only sometimes. What can be the possible reason for this? how can I stop this?
Any solution? Thank you..

Comment: Do you use Android studio 2.0 ? if so disable instant run and it will be fixed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Comment: how to do this? @Amir

Comment: Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run

Comment: this helped.. thank you.. can you please answer this so I can accept.@Amir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a strange issue with newly released `Android Studio 2.0` (same issue in 2.1) first time of launching application take longer than usual (e.g. 2, 3 seconds or sometimes screen blinks or goes black) this issue happens only in debug mode and not effect your released APK.

A temporary solution to fix this is disabling `instant run`:

```
Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make as rule to make all data loading in async tasks, you must check activity that you want to start where you load data.

The problem is in your second activity.
`oncreate` method should be used only to make `findviews` or start `async tasks`, don't load any in `oncreate` or in `onstart` or in `onresume`.
Probably you are loading high res images in sliding layout or you loading data in it.

There is another way, load all data in async task on first activity, then with ready data start second activity with already data loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can load slowly.

1. Android need to read your code from storage and load the classes into ram.
2. I assume `Utils.readSharedSetting(StartUpActivity.this, PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, "true")` reads from preferences. That's a file that you're reading from synchronously.
3. Actually launching the dialog takes a very small amount of time.

I'd suggest showing your loading inside the activity itself to minimize the work needed to render it.

Also, you can store `PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME` as a `boolean` instead of a `String`.

Comment: what is benefit of storing as boolean instead of String?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier while the performance difference will be negligible, semantically a boolean is much more clear because it's a boolean value, yes/no. Reading is also much simpler, since you know what to expect and don't have to worry how to parse a string.

Comment: should we start use `DataStore` for better performance instead of reading the whole file for exact. value? if yes, can I do migration from sharedPref to DataStore or I've t odd code replacement?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier sorry, can't answer that. It's been 5 years since I've done Android development.

Comment: it's okay thank you, bro, I see you are an awesome one can u be my mentor?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier not sure how I qualify for that, but I'll try to answer questions

Comment: Can we have connection? Moustafaelsaghier@gmail I need your help