# Android Studio gets black and freeze

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, gradle

My android studio version 2.1.2 recently started to get a black screen, freeze, and stop working.

[image]

Note: I added a very powerful and useful plugin called `Android WiFi ADB`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: if you use Android studio 2 disable instance run may fix your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459692/application-or-activity-takes-time-to-load-some-times/37460527#37460527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note 1: Can your computer run Android Studio? (Performance)

```
Step 1: Uninstall Android Studio
Step 2: Download a fresh copy of Android Studio
Step 3: Reinstall Android Studio
Step 4: Run Android Studio
Step 5: Create a basic application to check if Android Studio is OK
Step 6: Install the Android WiFi ADB plugin
Step 7: Do what you were doing before hand
```

Rather than asking people what the problem is, you should try to determine the cause of the problem first, by simply refreshing android studio step by step making sure each component works. If after doing these steps you are at the same conclusion then someone may be able to help you.