# Android: app startup stuck on black screen

Tags: android, startup

I'm developing an application for Android.
The app uses Google Play services, and require some permission.

The launcher activity is very simple and does nothing more than set the content view.
I'm testing it on various devices with following results:

**HOMTOM HT3 PRO, Android 5.1** Fast on showing first activity.

**HUAWEI P8 Lite, Android 6.0** Sometimes shows black screen for 5-10s before start

**Galaxy A3, Android 6.1** It's stuck on the black screen.

**Nexus 5** Stuck on black screen.

Here is some log from the Galaxy A3:

```
12-01 15:38:02.911 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:02.931 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59261438
12-01 15:38:03.291 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:03.331 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:03.331 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ab1c097 I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:03.381 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59261887
12-01 15:38:03.731 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:03.761 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59262266
12-01 15:38:04.121 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:04.171 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:04.171 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4f91b9e I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:04.221 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59262722
12-01 15:38:04.581 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:04.601 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59263105
12-01 15:38:04.961 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:05.001 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:05.001 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1cf681 I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:05.051 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59263551
12-01 15:38:05.391 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:05.421 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59263921
12-01 15:38:05.761 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:05.811 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:05.811 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7010fb0 I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:05.851 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59264352
12-01 15:38:06.181 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:06.211 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59264717
12-01 15:38:06.601 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:06.651 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:06.651 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{830db5b I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:06.691 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59265199
12-01 15:38:07.031 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
12-01 15:38:07.061 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59265564
12-01 15:38:07.431 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-01 15:38:07.491 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-01 15:38:07.491 16359-16359/com.package.appname D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7184a72 I.ED..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
12-01 15:38:07.531 16359-16359/com.package.appname I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.package.appname time:59266036
```

My Start Activity

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        //more code
    }

}
```

**But while debugging I clearly see that the waiting time is BEFORE the onCreate call.** May it depends by huge number of file that the app is composed by? I have 73 java classes + ~100 drawable.

FYI this is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "****",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "*****"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'br.com.instachat:emoji-library:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my Start layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/start_logo"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            ></View>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            ></View>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/start_progress"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/start_progress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/start_processing"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What API did you use to develop your simple application? What do you mean by "simple application"? Can you give us a code snippet,, maybe from your Java code or maybe your layout files? You say you need permissions to use your app, are those granted? Older phones sometimes do not show the pop up which asks the user for the permission it needs. You can enable them in the settings of the app on your phone.

Comment: I said "simple start activity", I attached it to my post. I will now try to check the permissions and let you know.

Comment: why is m3View null? can you show the layout and where m3View is initiated?

Comment: m3View it is not a my view. It is something system related I think. By the way I'm doing more tests on different devices, I will let you know asap.

Comment: Sorry it turns up that there was some more code on the onCreate method that was behaving badly. There is still some loading time at the beginning but It can be smoothed by setting `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` in your theme xml.

Comment: Moreover, I found another issue that can slow down the boot of the app, it is related to the Instant Run feature and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180591/android-app-launch-first-time-launch-is-taking-more-time-even-some-time-30-sec-a) it is explained how to fix it.