# LOGCAT showing error and my app doesn't opens even after successful build

Tags: java, android, logcat

My app does not open due to VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled logcat error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ess"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'
    mplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

> 2019-07-03 15:13:54.693 31220-31220/com.example.ess I/MultiDex:
>   Installing application 2019-07-03 15:13:54.693
>   31220-31220/com.example.ess I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support,
>   MultiDex support library is disabled. 2019-07-03 15:13:54.694
>   31220-31220/com.example.ess I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC
>   ClassLinker 2019-07-03 15:13:54.706 31220-31220/com.example.ess
>   I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for
>   12.807ms 2019-07-03 15:13:54.719 31220-31220/com.example.ess D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 2019-07-03 15:13:54.734
>   31220-31220/com.example.ess E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.ess, PID: 31220    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>         at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source:2)         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6632)
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6187)
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6093)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1801)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)         at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/base.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/lib/arm,
>   /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]         at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)        at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)         at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source:2)         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6632) 
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6187) 
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6093) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1801) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)         at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
>         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex
>   location (arm)
>   /data/app/com.example.ess-R5EW7cChwHRdpByd0M9SKw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>         at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)       at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)       at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:100)        at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:74)         at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)       at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)       at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:157)        at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>         at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>         at
>   android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
>         at
>   android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
>         at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:705)
>         at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:739)         at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:980)        at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2420)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6010)
>                 ... 8 more

LOGCAT now showing this[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J92Yt.png)

Comment: show Proguard rules and gradle.

Comment: show your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya edited my post with that

Comment: @KaranNayyar Kindly look at my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56867893/6314513

Comment: Check @Gowtham Subramaniam's answer 2nd point. It's major case for this error.

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam that worked but now i face this error i have updated in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.Add this dependency to your `gradle.build` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And enable `multiDexEnabled` to `true`

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**2**.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

> And you should use the same versions for the google support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[You can Follow This links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326575/vm-has-multidex-support-multidex-support-library-is-disabled)

check if you have any class has extended application. please add in the manifest file.